# How would I implement a guessing game with tkinter using things like input boxes and if statements

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help combining the guessing game I created with my Tkinter GUI. I need help mostly with how to use if statements with Tkinter and how to improve my GUI code because I feel like it could be made simpler.

Thank you in advance.

#### Tkinter GUI

```
from tkinter import *


#key function
def click():
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    output.delete(0.0, END)
    

#main:
window = Tk()
window.title("Guessing Game")
window.configure(background="lightskyblue1")

#BackgroundPhoto:
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="guessinggame.gif")
Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

#Label.1
Label (window, text="Enter your guess:", bg="lightskyblue1", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#InputBox
textentry = Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#CheckButton
Button(window, text="CHECK", width=6, command=click) .grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

#Label.2
Label (window, text="Your guess was:", bg="lightskyblue1", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

#OutputBox
output = Text(window, width=5, height=1, wrap=WORD, background="lightskyblue1")
output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, stick=W)

#mainloopRunner
window.mainloop()
```

#### Guessing Game

```
import random
affirmations = ('y', 'yeah', 'yes', 'yep', 'yup', 'sure')
print('I am thinking of a number from 1 to 10. Guess which one.')
number = random.randint(1, 10)
guesses = 1
while True:
    guess = int(input('Choose a number between 1 and 10: '))
    if guess == number:
        print('Wow, you got it after only {} guesses.'.format(guesses))
        play_again = input('Want to play again? [Y/N] ')
        if play_again.lower() in affirmations:
            guesses = 0 
            number = random.randint(1, 10) 
        else:
            print('Thanks for playing.')
            break
    elif 10 < guess < 1:
        print('Only guesses between 1 and 10, please.')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Think higher...')
    else:
        print('Go lower...')
    guesses += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code from the while loop in the original program in the `click()` function with a few alterations. As `click()` is a function you need to make the variable `guesses` global.

```
def click():
    global guesses
```

For communicating with the user you use the text area instead of printing. Clear text area before entering new text:

```
output.delete(0.0, END)             # Clear ouytout text area
output.insert('1.0', 'A message!')  # Display in text area
```

Otherwise you use `if` as usual.

With regards to the GUI code I can't see any obvious way to make it simpler.